# Scrapy: cannot reach second callback function when sending request with query parameter strings

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping engineering blogs from meta. Right now I am just trying to print the title and url for each blog. Thanks for any help

here is what I have done. It doesn't reach parse_loadmore function and doesn't print anything. I have tried copy and paste loadmore_endpoint to the browser and it just works fine, which is supposed to be some html code.

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import pdfkit
import requests
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from ..helpers import generate_pdfs_file_path

options = {
    # 'no-images': None,
    "disable-javascript": None,
    "disable-external-links": None,
    "quiet": None,
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
}


class MetaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "meta_spider"
    api_endpoint = "https://engineering.fb.com/wp-json/fb/v1/loadmore"
    start_urls = [
        "https://engineering.fb.com/category/core-infra/",
        # "https://engineering.fb.com/category/data-infrastructure/",
        # "https://engineering.fb.com/category/developer-tools/",
        # "https://engineering.fb.com/category/production-engineering/",
        # "https://engineering.fb.com/category/security/",
    ]
    post_fetched = 0

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_initial)
    def parse_initial(self, response):
        endpoint, query_args = get_loadmore_endpoints_and_params(response)
        for page in range(4):
            params = {
                "action": "loadmore",
                "queryArgs": json.dumps(query_args),
                "page": page,
                "post_type": "post",
            }
            loadmore_endpoint = get_load_more_posts_url(endpoint, params=params)
            # print(f"Sending Request {loadmore_endpoint}")
            yield scrapy.Request(url=loadmore_endpoint,  callback=self.parse_loadmore)

    def parse_loadmore(self, response):
        print("parse_loadmore called with response: {}".format(response.text))
        # Create a TextResponse object
        for post in response.css("article.post"):
            header = post.css("header.entry-header")
            title = header.css(".entry-title a::text").get().strip()
            url = header.css(".entry-title a::attr(href)").get()

            # Sanitize the title to create a valid filename
            safe_title = re.sub(r"[^\w\s-]", "", title).replace(" ", "_")
            print(f"----title: {safe_title}, url: {url}----")
  


def clean_post_html(soup):
    for script in soup.find_all("script"):
        script.decompose()
    for script in soup.find_all("noscript"):
        script.decompose()
    for element in soup.find_all(class_="sharedaddy"):
        element.decompose()

    image_container = soup.find(id="post-feat-image-container")
    if image_container:
        image_container.decompose()


def get_loadmore_endpoints_and_params(response):
    # Extracting the script content
    script_content = response.xpath(
        '//script[contains(., "loadmore_params")]/text()'
    ).get()

    # Parsing the JavaScript to extract query parameters
    if script_content:
        # Use regular expression to find the JSON object
        params_json = re.search(r"var loadmore_params = (.*?);", script_content)
        if params_json:
            params_string = params_json.group(1)
            params = json.loads(params_string)
            return params["restfulURL"], params["posts"]


def get_load_more_posts_url(url, params):
    query_string = urlencode(params, doseq=True)
    return f"{url}?{query_string}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things needed to achieve your goal.

1. In the `settings.py` or in your spiders `custom_settings` attribute set the default `"URLLENGTH_LIMIT"` to a higher value than the default - reason for this is because the load more endpoint is a very long URL and exceeds the limits imposed by scrapy by default
2. The response from your parse_loadmore method is typed as json, so it won't let you run css selectors on it. So the solution would be to initially call `response.json()` to get the text, and then manually stick the text into a `scrapy.Selector` and use that to run css and xpath queries on the html inside the string.

For example:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import re
import json
# from ..helpers import generate_pdfs_file_path

options = {
    # 'no-images': None,
    "disable-javascript": None,
    "disable-external-links": None,
    "quiet": None,
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
}


class MetaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "meta_spider"
    api_endpoint = "https://engineering.fb.com/wp-json/fb/v1/loadmore"
    start_urls = [
        "https://engineering.fb.com/category/core-infra/",
        # "https://engineering.fb.com/category/data-infrastructure/",
        # "https://engineering.fb.com/category/developer-tools/",
        # "https://engineering.fb.com/category/production-engineering/",
        # "https://engineering.fb.com/category/security/",
    ]
    post_fetched = 0
    custom_settings = {
        "URLLENGTH_LIMIT" : 20000
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_initial)
    def parse_initial(self, response):
        endpoint, query_args = get_loadmore_endpoints_and_params(response)
        for page in range(4):
            params = {
                "action": "loadmore",
                "queryArgs": json.dumps(query_args),
                "page": page,
                "post_type": "post",
            }
            loadmore_endpoint = get_load_more_posts_url(endpoint, params=params)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=loadmore_endpoint,  callback=self.parse_loadmore)

    def parse_loadmore(self, response):
        # print("parse_loadmore called with response: {}".format(response.text))

        resp = scrapy.Selector(text=response.json())

        for post in resp.css("article.post"):

            header = post.css("header.entry-header")
            title = header.css(".entry-title a::text").get().strip()
            url = header.css(".entry-title a::attr(href)").get()

            # Sanitize the title to create a valid filename
            safe_title = re.sub(r"[^\w\s-]", "", title).replace(" ", "_")
            print(f"----title: {safe_title}, url: {url}----")



def clean_post_html(soup):
    for script in soup.find_all("script"):
        script.decompose()
    for script in soup.find_all("noscript"):
        script.decompose()
    for element in soup.find_all(class_="sharedaddy"):
        element.decompose()

    image_container = soup.find(id="post-feat-image-container")
    if image_container:
        image_container.decompose()


def get_loadmore_endpoints_and_params(response):
    # Extracting the script content
    script_content = response.xpath(
        '//script[contains(., "loadmore_params")]/text()'
    ).get()
    # Parsing the JavaScript to extract query parameters
    if script_content:
        # Use regular expression to find the JSON object
        params_json = re.search(r"var loadmore_params = (.*?);", script_content)
        if params_json:
            params_string = params_json.group(1)
            params = json.loads(params_string)
            return params["restfulURL"], params["posts"]


def get_load_more_posts_url(url, params):
    query_string = urlencode(params, doseq=True)
    return f"{url}?{query_string}"
```

##### PARTIAL OUTPUT

```
2023-11-23 19:42:48 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-11-23 19:42:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://engineering.fb.com/category/core-infra/> (referer: None)
2023-11-23 19:42:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://engineering.fb.com/wp-json/fb/v1/loadmore?action=loadmore&queryArgs=%22%7B%5C%22category_name%5C%22%3A%5C%22core-infra%5C%22%2C%5C%22error%5C%
22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22m%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22p%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22post_parent%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22subpost%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22subpost_id%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22attachment%5C%22%3A%5C....5C%22order%5C%22%3A%5C%22DESC%5C%22%7D%22&page=3&post_type=post> (referer: https://engineering.fb.com/category/core-infra/)
2023-11-23 19:42:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://engineering.fb.com/wp-json/fb/v1/loadmore?action=loadmore&queryArgs=%22%7B%5C%22category_name%5C%22%3A%5C%22core-infra%5C%22%2C%5C%22error%5C%
22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22m%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22p%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22post_parent%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22subpost%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22subpost_id%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22attachment%5C%22%3A%5C....%22&page=0&post_type=post> (referer: https://engineering.fb.com/category/core-infra/)
2023-11-23 19:42:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://engineering.fb.com/wp-json/fb/v1/loadmore?action=loadmore&queryArgs=%22%7B%5C%22category_name%5C%22%3A%5C%22core-infra%5C%22%2C%5C%22error%5C%
22%3A%5C%22...e%5C%22%3A%5C%2250%5C%22%2C%5C%22no_found_rows%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C
%22order%5C%22%3A%5C%22DESC%5C%22%7D%22&page=1&post_type=post> (referer: https://engineering.fb.com/category/core-infra/)
2023-11-23 19:42:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://engineering.fb.com/wp-json/fb/v1/loadmore?action=loadmore&queryArgs=%22%7B%5C%22category_name%5C%22%3A%5C%22core-infra%5C%22%2C%5C%22error%5C%
22%3A%5C%22%5C...2%3Atrue%2C%5C%22post_type%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%22%2C%5C%22posts_per_page%5C%22%3A12%2C%5C%22nopaging%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C%22comments_per_page%5C%22%3A%5C%2250%5C%22%2C%5C%22no_found_rows%5C%22%3Afalse%2C%5C
%22order%5C%22%3A%5C%22DESC%5C%22%7D%22&page=2&post_type=post> (referer: https://engineering.fb.com/category/core-infra/)
----title: Introducing_Velox_An_open_source_unified_execution_engine, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/03/09/open-source/velox-open-source-execution-engine/----
----title: Metas_head_of_AR_hardware_on_the_future_of_AR, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/02/24/virtual-reality/ar-vr-meta-caitlin-kalinowski/----
----title: How_Meta_brought_AV1_to_Reels, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/02/21/video-engineering/av1-codec-facebook-instagram-reels/----
----title: Inside_Metas_first_smart_glasses, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/02/16/virtual-reality/developing-meta-rayban-stories/----
----title: Building_a_cross-platform_runtime_for_AR, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/02/13/virtual-reality/meta-ar-augmented-reality-cross-platform-runtime/----
----title: Improving_Metas_global_maps, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/02/07/web/basemap-facebook-instagram-whatsapp-improvements/----
----title: The_evolution_of_Facebooks_iOS_app_architecture, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/02/06/ios/facebook-ios-app-architecture/----
----title: Asynchronous_computing_at_Meta_Overview_and_learnings, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/01/31/production-engineering/meta-asynchronous-computing/----
----title: Watch_Metas_engineers_discuss_optimizing_large-scale_networks, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/01/27/networking-traffic/optimizing-large-scale-networks-meta-engineers/----
----title: Tulip_Modernizing_Metas_data_platform, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/01/26/data-infrastructure/tulip-modernizing-metas-data-platform/----
----title: Open-sourcing_Anonymous_Credential_Service, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2022/12/12/security/anonymous-credential-service-acs-open-source/----
----title: Enabling_static_analysis_of_SQL_queries_at_Meta, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2022/11/30/data-infrastructure/static-analysis-sql-queries/----
----title: Writing_and_linting_Python_at_scale, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/11/21/production-engineering/writing-linting-python-at-scale-meta/----
----title: Watch_Metas_engineers_on_building_network_infrastructure_for_AI, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/11/15/networking-traffic/watch-metas-engineers-on-building-network-infrastructure-for-ai/----
----title: Enhancing_the_security_of_WhatsApp_calls, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/11/08/security/whatsapp-calls-enhancing-security/----
----title: How_Meta_built_Threads_in_5_months, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/11/06/android/how-meta-built-threads-in-5-months/----
----title: Automating_data_removal, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/10/31/data-infrastructure/automating-data-removal/----
----title: Automating_dead_code_cleanup, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/10/24/data-infrastructure/automating-dead-code-cleanup/----
----title: 5_Things_you_didnt_know_about_Buck2, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/10/23/developer-tools/5-things-you-didnt-know-about-buck2/----
----title: How_Meta_is_creating_custom_silicon_for_AI, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/10/18/ml-applications/meta-ai-custom-silicon-olivia-wu/----
----title: Automating_product_deprecation, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/10/17/data-infrastructure/automating-product-deprecation-meta/----
----title: Meta_contributes_new_features_to_Python_312, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/10/05/developer-tools/python-312-meta-new-features/----
----title: Meta_Quest_2_Defense_through_offense, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/09/12/security/meta-quest-2-defense-through-offense/----
----title: Using_Chakra_execution_traces_for_benchmarking_and_network_performance_optimization, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/09/07/networking-traffic/chakra-execution-traces-benchmarking-network-performance-op
timization/----
----title: Arcadia_An_end-to-end_AI_system_performance_simulator, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/09/07/data-infrastructure/arcadia-end-to-end-ai-system-performance-simulator/----
----title: Threads_The_inside_story_of_Metas_newest_social_app, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/09/07/culture/threads-inside-story-metas-newest-social-app/----
----title: What_is_it_like_to_write_code_at_Meta, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/09/05/web/what-like-ship-code-meta-tech-podcast/----
----title: Scheduling_Jupyter_Notebooks_at_Meta, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/08/29/security/scheduling-jupyter-notebooks-meta/----
----title: Code_Llama_Metas_state-of-the-art_LLM_for_coding, url: https://ai.meta.com/blog/code-llama-large-language-model-coding/----
----title: Introducing_Immortal_Objects_for_Python, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/08/15/developer-tools/immortal-objects-for-python-instagram-meta/----
----title: Meta_Connect_2023_September_27__28, url: https://www.meta.com/blog/quest/connect-2023-september-27-28-menlo-park-vr-ai----
----title: Scaling_the_Instagram_Explore_recommendations_system, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/08/09/ml-applications/scaling-instagram-explore-recommendations-system/----
----title: How_Meta_is_improving_password_security_and_preserving_privacy, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/08/08/security/how-meta-is-improving-password-security-and-preserving-privacy/----
----title: Fixit_2_Metas_next-generation_auto-fixing_linter, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/08/07/developer-tools/fixit-2-linter-meta/----
----title: Using_short-lived_certificates_to_protect_TLS_secrets, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/08/07/security/short-lived-certificates-protect-tls-secrets/----
----title: Bringing_HDR_video_to_Reels, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/07/17/video-engineering/hdr-video-reels-meta/----
----title: Metas_Evenstar_is_transitioning_to_OCP_to_accelerate_open_RAN_adoption, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/06/29/connectivity/evenstar-meta-ocp-open-ran/----
----title: Meta_developer_tools_Working_at_scale, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/06/27/developer-tools/meta-developer-tools-open-source/----
----title: Bombyx_is_being_licensed_for_product_development, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/05/22/connectivity/bombyx-meta-fiber-deployment-robot-product-development/----
----title: MSVP_is_Metas_first_video_processing_ASIC, url: https://ai.facebook.com/blog/meta-scalable-video-processor-MSVP----
----title: Meta_introduces_its_first-generation_AI_inference_accelerator, url: https://ai.facebook.com/blog/meta-training-inference-accelerator-AI-MTIA----
----title: Building_and_deploying_MySQL_Raft_at_Meta, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/05/16/data-infrastructure/mysql-raft-meta/----
----title: The_malware_threat_landscape_NodeStealer_DuckTail_and_more, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/05/03/security/malware-nodestealer-ducktail/----
----title: A_fine-grained_network_traffic_analysis_with_Millisampler, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/04/17/networking-traffic/millisampler-network-traffic-analysis/----
----title: Deploying_key_transparency_at_WhatsApp, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/04/13/security/whatsapp-key-transparency/----
----title: How_Device_Verification_protects_your_WhatsApp_account, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/04/13/security/whatsapp-device-verification-protects-your-account/----
----title: Why_xHE-AAC_is_being_embraced_at_Meta, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/04/11/video-engineering/high-quality-audio-xhe-aac-codec-meta/----
----title: Build_faster_with_Buck2_Our_open_source_build_system, url: https://engineering.fb.com/2023/04/06/open-source/buck2-open-source-large-scale-build-system/----
2023-11-23 19:42:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-11-23 19:42:49 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 13747,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
```